# JS: extracting a resolve in Promise is not getting same result

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following block of code:

```
async done() => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>   {
       const events = new Map();
       events.set('CLOSE_CLICK_EVENT', () => {
         //other logic
         resolve(false); 
       });
   }
}
```

I am trying to removing the "other logic" to an external function.  My other approach is below:

revised approach:

```
async done() => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>   {
       const events = new Map();
       events.set('CLOSE_CLICK_EVENT', () => {
          return this._doneCloseButtonHandler(events);
       });
   }
}

async _doneCloseButtonHandler(events) {
    //other logic
     return false;
}
```

The 2nd approach doesn't seem to be behaving the same way though -- why is the Promise being resolved differently?  The Promise doesn't seem to be getting resolved when I try to use the 2nd approach.

Comment: Returning an async function does not resolve the promise. You will still need to resolve it by calling `resolve()`

Comment: "*The Promise doesn't seem to be getting resolved*" - well, you're no longer calling `resolve` but use `return` for some reason?

Comment: Can you show the actual code for `// other logic`, please? Especially what are you doing with `events`?

Answer (score 0):

In the second approach, you are never calling the `resolve` function, so it cannot resolve, you need to chain it:

```
return this._doneCloseButtonHandler(events).then(resolve, reject);
```

Edit: based on OP's request, there is also a way to resolve within the `_doneCloseButtonHandler` function when you pass the `resolve` as argument:

```
return this._doneCloseButtonHandler(events, resolve)

// ...

function _doneCloseButtonHandler(event, resolve) {
    // ....
    resolve()
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to resolve it within the `_doneCloseButtonHandler` function?

Comment: Yes, I'm gonna edit the answer

Comment: @sal3jfc Yes, but don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the "other logic", you should first refactor your function to

```
async done() {
   const _ = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>   {
     const events = new Map();
     events.set('CLOSE_CLICK_EVENT', resolve);
     // do something with `events`
   });
   // other logic that should happen when the CLOSE_CLICK event occurs
   return false;
}
```

(the `_` corresponds to whatever will be passed to the `resolve` call).

Then you can extract the other logic into a separate function.